# Difference between decode and unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

According to this test:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

ENCODING = 'utf-8'

# what is the difference between decode and unicode?
test_cases = [
    'aaaaa',
    'ááááá',
    'ℕℤℚℝℂ',
]
FORMAT = '%-10s %5d %-10s %-10s %5d %-10s %10s'
for text in test_cases :
    decoded = text.decode(ENCODING)
    unicoded = unicode(text, ENCODING)
    equal = decoded == unicoded
    print FORMAT % (decoded, len(decoded), type(decoded), unicoded, len(unicoded), type(unicoded), equal)
```

There is no difference between `.decode()` and `unicode()`:

```
aaaaa          5 <type 'unicode'> aaaaa          5 <type 'unicode'>       True
ááááá          5 <type 'unicode'> ááááá          5 <type 'unicode'>       True
ℕℤℚℝℂ          5 <type 'unicode'> ℕℤℚℝℂ          5 <type 'unicode'>       True
```

Am I right? If so, why do we have two different ways of accomplishing the same thing? Which one should I use? Is there any subtle difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comparing the documentation for the two functions ([here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode)), the differences between the two methods seem indeed very minor.  The `unicode` function is documented as

> If encoding and/or errors are given, unicode() will decode the object
>   which can either be an 8-bit string or a character buffer using the
>   codec for encoding. The encoding parameter is a string giving the name
>   of an encoding; if the encoding is not known, LookupError is raised.
>   Error handling is done according to errors; this specifies the
>   treatment of characters which are invalid in the input encoding. If
>   errors is 'strict' (the default), a ValueError is raised on errors,
>   ...

whereas the description for `string.decode` states

> Decodes the string using the codec registered for encoding. encoding
>   defaults to the default string encoding. errors may be given to set a
>   different error handling scheme. The default is 'strict', meaning that
>   encoding errors raise UnicodeError. ...

Thus, the only differences seem to be that `unicode` also works for character buffers and that the error returned for invalid input differs (`ValueError` vs. `UnicodeError`).  Another, minor difference is in backwards compatibility: `unicode` is documented as being "New in version 2.0" whereas `string.decode` is "New in version 2.2".

Given the above, which method to use seems to be entirely a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

decode:
Decodes the string using the codec registered for encoding. encoding defaults to the default string encoding.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?#str.decode

unicode:
Return the Unicode string version of object [...].
See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode

Since you have UTF-8 as your encoding, the functions return the same. If you choose another encoding, they should return different things.

Comment: I am talking about decode, not encode. Besides, both to decode and unicode I can explicitly pass an encoding parameter. So what is the difference?

Comment: Right, I changed it to decode. The point I was trying to make did not change, though. You _can_ pass an argument, but you don't have to. In case you don't, the functions may return different things, depending on your encoding. In case you pass the argument, @jochen covered the minor differences, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

When the value you're using is a `str`, and the encoding you are using is a Unicode charset, there is no functional difference. But:

1. `u.decode(e)` is a convenience method which may be slightly more readable in chained expressions than calling `unicode(s,e)`.
2. There are also string transformations that are not connected to Unicode encoding/decoding, like `base64` or `string-escape`, which can be used in `encode()`/`decode()` but not `unicode()`. (It is generally now considered that putting them in the same place as Unicode charsets was a mistake; they're removed in Python 3 and will likely end up in a separate method pair.)
3. `unicode()` as a constructor can take types other than `str` that you might want to generate a Unicode string representation for.